# Android Studio - Disabling back button on default Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, android-fragments, android-activity

So I have created the default Navigation Drawer Activity, and have added my own buttons along the bottom to manually change the fragment.

However, I dont want these buttons to add to the back stack as I want the navigation menue to always show the hamburger menu instead of a back button.menu I essentially want to disable the back button and stack from showing up when I change fragments on the navigation drawer. How would I achieve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jThI1.jpg

This is in the navigation activity in onCreate

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_projects,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        this.navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, this.navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, this.navController);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the NavController.OnNavigatedListener to update the toolbar icon.

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_navHost)
navController.addOnNavigatedListener(contoller, destination -> {
   if(destination.id == R.id.fragmentTwo){
          // update the toolbar here
}
    })
```